# Finding links in text and checking if there are any whitespaces in it

Tags: html, regex, whitespace

I am trying to parse html fragment to find if there are any whitespaces inside 'href' or 'src' attributes of tags.
So far i managed to come up with this regular expression:

```
(src|href)(\s*=\s*)(["'])(.+(?=\s).+)\3
```

But it can go false positive if there is a whitespace after closing quote symbol, which makes it kinda useless. 
How can it be modified ?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/JXp6pZ/1

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - use a parser.  [`(?:src|href)\s*=\s*(["']?)\S*\1`](https://regex101.com/r/JXp6pZ/2) should work for you though

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://regex101.com/r/JXp6pZ/3

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but that does opposite of what is needed. It reutrns positive if there are no whitespaces, but it need positive only if it has whitespace somewhere in src or href.

Comment: So you want [`\b(?:src|href)\s*=\s*(?:'[^']*\s[^']*'|"[^"]*\s[^"]*")`](https://regex101.com/r/JXp6pZ/6)?

Comment: Yes, that's doing nice work, but i wonder if it can be any simpler ?

Comment: As pointed out above, do not use a regex. Use a parser. HTML is not regular; **regular** expressions are not a suitable tool for the job.

Comment: `(?:src|href)=.[^'"]*\s` https://regex101.com/r/VVwW5y/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/BFTY83/1):

```
(?:src|href)=.[^'"]*\s[^'"]*['"]
```

*we use `.` for the first double/single quote because we don't care which it is, thereby making a slightly simpler pattern to read